# Learning machine learning through guided discovery

Tags: machine-learning, references

There is a [huge thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104996/big-list-of-guided-discovery-books) on learning mathematics through guided discovery over at math SE. I hope we can get one here as well.

I am currently trying to get through Pattern Classification by Duda et al (for a course). However, the book seems too dense for me. It seems like a topic that could be better learned through guided discovery. Are there any books out there that teach one or more of the topics in pattern recognition through guided discovery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Guided Discovery. But 'Introduction to Statistical Learning' by Hastie et al. is definately a good book. It also includes examples with R code. I would also recommend the more advanced book 'Elements of Statistical Learning' (same authors). In addition, you could consider having a look at Kaggle. There is an active community sharing and discussing about machine learning applications.